# how to split a column in dataframe into list of tuple

Tags: python, list, dataframe, split, tuples

I found some answers online, but I have no experience with regular expressions, which I believe is what is needed here and if there is another way it would be better.

I have a complexed column in my dataframe that needs to be split by either a ','  ';'  '('  ')' ':'

Example string:

```
(36%) (litopenaaus varmrn ), une chapelure (25%) [vmaaî fmur, water,) sel, soja 0i), sucre, levure), eau. î farine de whca, amidon de mais, sart, cre. regulators (450, 500, stg). soybean [containing an antioxidant (300)]. sucre, powder of gariic, levure, th ci nœ (412). contient des crevettes"
```

should be split into a list containing the following

```
["36%", "litopenaaus varmrn", "une chapelure (25%)", ["vmaaî fmur", "water", "sel", "soja 0i", "sucre", "levure"], "eau. î farine de whca", "amidon de mais", "sart", "cre. regulators ["(450, 500, stg)"]. soybean [containing an antioxidant (300)]. sucre", "powder of gariic", "levure"," th ci nœ (412). contient des crevettes"]
```

The code I have written to do this looks like this but nothing happend:

```
delimiters = ",", ":", "(", ")", ";"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))

df['splited'] = df.ingredient.apply(lambda row: ' '.join((re.split(regexPattern, str(row)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
delimiters = ",", ":", "(", ")", ";"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))

df['splited'] = df.ingredient.apply(lambda row: ' '.join((re.split(regexPattern, str(row)))))
```

you actually splitted (`re.split`) and then joined created parts using space character (`' '.join`), if you need parts list rather than single new string simply do not join them, i.e.

```
df['splited'] = df.ingredient.apply(lambda row: re.split(regexPattern, str(row)))
```

Comment: this split the string by the delimiters well but i need to split it into list of tuples. Do you know how it work ?